# alternatives to strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am having difficulties using `strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index` as the number of periods for `ta.highest` in pine-script:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

barsSinceEntry =  strategy.opentrades > 0 ? bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1) : na

longEntryCond =  ta.rising(ta.mom(ohlc4, 1), 3)

if (longEntryCond)
    strategy.entry("L", strategy.long)

longExitCond = ((ta.highest(nz(ohlc4[1]), 30) - ohlc4) >= ta.atr(200))

if (longExitCond)
    strategy.close("L")
```

When I use `barsSinceEntry` instead of `30` for the exit condition in this example, this is the error message:
"Error on bar 0: Invalid value of the 'length' argument (NaN) in the '[object Object]' function. It must be > 0."

Are there any alternatives? I don't quite understand how `strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(trade_num)` works.

The reference manual says it returns the bar_index of the open trade's entry and trade_num (series int) is "the trade number of the open trade. The number of the first trade is zero".  How to tell the *number of the trade*?

Answer (score 1):

Use `math.max(1, nz(barsSinceEntry))` instead.
Like the error message says, ta.highest() expects an integer greater than 0. barsSinceEntry can be an *na* object ob even 0. So make sure it's not na in the first place then make sure you call ta.highest() with at least 1.

Comment: Thank you! It works now.  I'll remember functions similar to ` ta.barssince` have such requirements.